# URLSearchParams API always return an empty object from url parsing

Tags: javascript, urlsearchparams

My question is pretty simple. I try to use the URLSearchParams API.
In my Google chrome browser console I got an empty object returned.

I simply applied the example given here [google example](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams)

```js
// Can also constructor from another URLSearchParams
const params = new URLSearchParams('q=search+string&version=1&person=Eric');

console.log(params.get('q') === "search string");
console.log(params.get('version') === "1");
console.log(Array.from(params).length === 3);
```

But I always got an empty object

[image: console output]

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but I got completely different responses in the console using the inputs you provided. `Object.fromEntries(params)` worked fine as well

Comment: I converted you code into a live demo and can't reproduce the problem

Comment: im getting `true` `true` `true`.. did you modify your browser in some strange way?

Comment: ...e.g. like prototype modifications?

Comment: No. I did not modified anything in my browser....a plain Google Chrome browser

Comment: so we can agree the problem is something more than `URLSearchParams`?

Comment: If you run the snippet in this post, what do you get?

Comment: weird....I tried to reinstall chrome but it still does not work. Anyone has an idea from where I could start searching what could be the problem ?

Comment: @FZs : I ran this snippet in chromium and it worked perfectly....but in plain chrome brwoser it does not work ...seems to be a really weird issue with chrome. I do not know how to prevent it from other  browser to occured... I'll try to search for an alternative

Comment: @jossefaz This seems to have nothing to do with the browser. Chrome uses Chromium, so they should be the same. What site were you on when testing for the first time? That site could've modified it.

Comment: @FZs I tested all this on different website...but mainly on my localhost (React 17+ Dev)

Comment: @jossefaz Were you able to repro this on any site other than your own?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229657/discussion-between-jossefaz-and-fzs).